# How to retrieve single sqlite column and store rows into array

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-emulator, android-sqlite

Im new to android, and i use Sqlite to store an array of type double into a column called "KEY_VALUE"

```
public long createEntry(Double rates) { 
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_VALUE, rates);
    return ourDatabase.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

I put the data into the columns here via another class

```
for(i=0;i<37;i++){
    entry.createEntry((theRSSHandler.rates()[i]));
    }
```

Now i would like to retrieve the column i saved and get each row as an array element, ive seen and tried other similar solutions but they have not worked.
Here is the method i use to try and get the column data But it has failed.

```
public Double[] getData() {
    String[] col = {KEY_VALUE}; 
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE, col, KEY_VALUE , null, null, null, null);
    Double[] result = null;

    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }

    int iVal = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result[c.getPosition()] = c.getDouble(iVal);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `it has failed`...how? can you show the LogCat?

Comment: it shows null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to put values in an array that has not been initialized.

```
  Double[] result = null;
```

needs to be followed up with something like...

```
  result = new Double[100];
```

i think you probably want to initialize it with the number of records pointed to by the cursor

```
  result = new Double[c.count()];
```

Comment: i could be slightly off on the syntax, as i'm doing this from memory (all my "good" code is at work.)